# Membership acces Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I used gutenwp Theme and tutor lms pro to create an online courses website wheren users can register but I want to put an restriction over courses page to be possible to see the courses just if the user pay the membership.I user paymembership pro, restrict content pro but they aren`t working.If someone can tell me a better solution, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I am from the Tutor LMS team. We have not added individual course pages support and require membership at this moment.

We will communicate with Paid Memberships Pro team to improve our integration and update you here.

If you need this feature right now, you may have to hire a developer. In that case, you may contact Tutor LMS support to get some ideas to get starter and which files and actions, filters and hooks to customize.